How to knowing number of clusters when using SOM?
SOM uses neural network. The output layer of SOM should be neurons position. As the model is training, neuron's position started to moving to the closer of centroid of clusters.
The output layer was just telling neuron position, but it didn't tell how many clusters of entire dataset.
So, can SOM tell us how many clusters detected?
